# airflow sla_miss_callback does not trigger custom function

Tags: airflow

Apache Airflow 1.10.7
I would like to have custom function to be triggered on sla miss on task.
I am setting this property during dag initialization

```
def sla_callback_function():
    # custom logic

dag=DAG('sla_test', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='00 10 * * *', sla_miss_callback=sla_callback_function)
```

SLA time is set on task level (only 1 task). I received SLA miss emails and see SLA misses in UI but I don't see the custom function getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

i know its very late to answer this question but just in case if you are still looking for answers then this might help. Your custom function definition should be something like below:

```
def sla_callback_function(*args):
    # custom logic

dag=DAG('sla_test', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 10 * * *', sla_miss_callback=sla_callback_function)
```

Answer (score -2):

try to pass parameter for the function , sla_miss_callback=sla_callback_function()